# Как создать объект с помощью Expression имея только имя типа?

Tags: c#, рефлексия, .net-6, expressions

У меня есть название типа которое я беру из `Assembly.GetExecutionAssembly().GetType("MyTypeName")` и я не хочу пользоваться `Activator.CreateInstance`, а хочу использовать `Expression`, но проблема в том, что я не могу использовать Generic. Как можно имея объект `System.Type` создать инстанс объекта с помощью `Expression`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static object CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    Func<object> func = Expression
        .Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.New(type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)))
        .Compile();
    return func();
}
```

Если нужна производительность, то скомпилированное выражение надо кешировать. Например так:

```
static Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> creators = new();

static object CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    if (!creators.TryGetValue(type, out Func<object> func))
    {
        func = Expression
            .Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.New(type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)))
            .Compile();
        creators[type] = func;
    }
    return func();
}
```

Больше примеров можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972767/12888024).

---

Проверяем

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type type = typeof(List<>);
    var gen = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
    var obj = CreateInstance(gen);
    var info = gen.GetMethod("Add");
            
    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
        info.Invoke(obj, new object[] { i });

    Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", (IEnumerable<int>)obj));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Выражение не строится, `Internal Error evaluating expression`, попробовал просто с Generic - тоже самое

Comment: @Kalmankantaja конструктор по умолчанию (тот что без аргументов), должен быть публичным. Только что проверил - работает. Даже с обобщенными типами работает.

Comment: не помогло, .NET 6, C# 10

Comment: @Kalmankantaja добавил пример в ответ.